# JSON schema for array of different types

Tags: json, validation, jsonschema

I have very basic schema that behaves somehow strange.

```
{
"$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-04/schema#",
"type": "object",
"properties": 
{
    "$out": 
    {
        "type": "array",
        "minItems": 1,
        "items": {
            "oneOf": [
                { "type": "string" },
                { "$ref": "#/definitions/alias" }
            ]
        }
    }
},
"definitions": 
{
    "alias": 
    {
        "properties": 
        {
            "$source": { "type": "string" },
            "$alias": { "type": "string" }
        },
        "required": [ "$source", "$alias" ],
        "additionalProperties": false
    }
}
```

}

If I use the following JSON to test:

```
{
    "$out": [
        "12w",
        { "$source": "WH.Code", "$alias": "WarehouseCode"}
    ] 
}
```

It fails ([sample](http://geraintluff.github.io/tv4/try/#?data=%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%22shape%22%3A%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22thetype%22%3A%20%22circle%22%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22shade%22%3A%22red%22%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%7D&schema=%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%22type%22%3A%20%22object%22%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%22properties%22%3A%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22shape%22%3A%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22oneOf%22%3A%20%5B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7B%20%22%24ref%22%3A%22%23%2Fdefinitions%2FsquareSchema%22%20%7D%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7B%20%22%24ref%22%3A%22%23%2Fdefinitions%2FcircleSchema%22%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%5D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%22definitions%22%3A%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22squareSchema%22%3A%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22type%22%3A%20%22object%22%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22properties%22%3A%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22thetype%22%3A%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22type%22%3A%20%22string%22%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22enum%22%3A%20%5B%22square%22%5D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22colour%22%3A%7B%7D%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22shade%22%3A%7B%7D%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22boxname%22%3A%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22type%22%3A%22string%22%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22oneOf%22%3A%5B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7B%20%22%24ref%22%3A%22%23%2Fdefinitions%2FcolourSchema%22%20%7D%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7B%20%22%24ref%22%3A%22%23%2Fdefinitions%2FshadeSchema%22%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%5D%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22required%22%3A%20%5B%22thetype%22%2C%20%22boxname%22%5D%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22additionalProperties%22%3Afalse%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22circleSchema%22%3A%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22type%22%3A%20%22object%22%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22properties%22%3A%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22thetype%22%3A%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22type%22%3A%20%22string%22%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22enum%22%3A%5B%22circle%22%5D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22colour%22%3A%7B%7D%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22shade%22%3A%7B%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22oneOf%22%3A%5B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7B%20%22%24ref%22%3A%22%23%2Fdefinitions%2FcolourSchema%22%20%7D%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7B%20%22%24ref%22%3A%22%23%2Fdefinitions%2FshadeSchema%22%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%5D%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22additionalProperties%22%3Afalse%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22colourSchema%22%3A%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22type%22%3A%22object%22%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22properties%22%3A%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22colour%22%3A%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22type%22%3A%22string%22%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22shade%22%3A%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22type%22%3A%22null%22%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22shadeSchema%22%3A%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22type%22%3A%22object%22%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22properties%22%3A%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22shade%22%3A%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22type%22%3A%22string%22%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22colour%22%3A%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22type%22%3A%22null%22%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%7D)) saying that string element in array is valid agains more that one schema. If I change reference to 'alias' with say just                     { "type": "string" } it works as expected. What am I doing wrong?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All of the keywords you use (`properties`, `required`, `additionalProperties`) only apply if the value is an object.  Because there nothing requiring that the value be an object, anything that is not an object will pass.  The object keywords are only taken into account if it is an object.

There are a number of ways you can make the schema work, but the most straight forward is to add `"type": "object"` to your `alias` schema.